# Renaming html files according to <title> tag

Tags: linux, script

I have a folder with a bunch of html files numbered sequentially (file1.html, file2.html, etc).

I would like to rename each file according to the  tag in each file.

So if file1.html contains `<title>Page Name</title>`, I would like the script to rename the file `Page Name.html`.

How do I do this on linux?

Comment: Sanity check: Are all titles unique?  (Check this with grep title *.html ). If not you are ending up with duplicate file names (or rather, with errors or lost files when two files try to get renamed to the same file name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a very simplistic approach assuming your document is somewhat well formed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in *.html;
do
   title=$( grep -oP '(?<=<title>).*(?=<\/title>)' "$f" )
   mv -i "$f" "${title//[^a-zA-Z0-9\._\- ]}".html   
done
```

Some explanation of what happens:

- To get only the actual title, we'll use `grep` and Perl regular expressions. There are look-aheads and look-behinds to filter out the actual HTML tags and only get the title. It's a complicated-looking regex, but you can't easily output only the captures with `grep`.
- Make sure to always quote your variables (`"$f")` so the whole thing works if files have whitespace in their name.
- By default `mv` will overwrite existing files. Use `mv -i` to avoid that and have your shell prompt you before overwriting.
- Any character except letters, numbers, `.`, `_` and `-`, as well as a space, will be removed from the file name. We do this with [substring replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).
- To remove all whitespace, use `mv -i "$f" "${title//[^a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]}".html`
- To keep the actual page title as-is, simply use `mv "$f" "$title".html`.

Comment: Use mv -i or some other method to prevent losing files with duped titles. Also consider adding something with tr or sed to replace non-alphanumerical characters with _ or something.

Comment: `mv` will not overwrite an existing file unless you use `-f`.

Comment: @ott yes it will. At least on any Linux system I have ever used. You may have `mv` set up as an alias to `mv -i` on your system.

Comment: Arg. There was an `alias mv='mv -n'`, which acts silently (and does not overwrite an existing file).

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks for the suggestion. Did some sanitizing there.

Comment: This script renamed the files as promised, but it didn't remove the spaces in the name. I hadn't asked for that but it would be nice if that was also working.

Comment: @ToDo For that you'll need to remove the space at the end of the expression before `]}".html`